# UITableView is null after first data load, reloadData does not work

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a custom UIView with a UITableView in it. I connect the delegate and dataSource via interface builder, it looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/nj9elaj4h/ (may not upload images yet :( )

When I load the view, the data is displayed as it should be. But when I try to call reloadData, nothing happens. I checked if the uitableview is set, but it is NULL. But as soon as I drag the tableView and it reloads it views, the new data is presented. Anyone got an idea why reloadData does not work?

.h looks like this:

```
@interface NextTitleView :   UIView<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,SociusClientDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,Ne     xtTitleCustomCellDelegate>
 {
NexTitleCustomCell* _cellInFocus;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView* _tableViewNextTitle;

@end
```

thanks for your help :D

EDIT: Added .m file

```
@implementation NextTitleView
@synthesize _tableViewNextTitle;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

  -(id)init
{
if(self)
{
    [SharedSingeltons sharedInstance]._client.delegateCustomClient = self;
    _tableViewNextTitle = [[UITableView alloc]init];
}

return self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
return 2;
}

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(section == 0)
    return @"Now playing";
if(section == 1)
    return @"Comming Next";
else
    return @"";
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(section == 0)
    return 1;
if (section == 1)
    return [[SharedSingeltons sharedInstance]._client._musicList count];
else
    return 0;

  }

-(NexTitleCustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{

NexTitleCustomCell* cell = [[NexTitleCustomCell alloc]init];
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NextTitleCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

MusicItem* item = [[SharedSingeltons sharedInstance]._client._musicList
                   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.delegate = self;
cell._labelSongTitle.text = item._songTitle;
cell._labelSongTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell._labelSubtitle.text = item._artist;
cell._identifier = item._songIdentifier;
cell._labelRating.text = item._rating.stringValue;

return cell;
 }

-(void)clientDidReceiveMusicList:(SociusClient *)sender list:(NSMutableArray *)array
  {
   for(MusicItem* item in [SharedSingeltons sharedInstance]._client._musicList)
{
    NSLog(@"rating:%@",item._rating);
}
NSLog(@"TAbleVIEW:%@",_tableViewNextTitle);
[self._tableViewNextTitle reloadData];

}

  -(void)didPressActionButton:(NexTitleCustomCell *)sender
    {
     NSLog(@"Show alert view");

   _cellInFocus = sender;
      UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil  delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Vote Up",  @"Like",@"Remember", nil];
[popupQuery showInView:self];
   }

  -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
   {
      if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
    NSLog(@"Vote up");
    [self sendUpdateVoteForSong];
   }
   }

 -(void)sendUpdateVoteForSong
{
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:_cellInFocus._identifier forKey:@"Vote"];
NSLog(@"Identifier:%@",_cellInFocus._identifier);

[[SharedSingeltons sharedInstance]._client sendObject:dict error:nil];
 }



    @end
```

Comment: where you put reloadData ???

Comment: Post the whole .m for NextTitleView please

Comment: In your init you haven't called self=[super init]

Comment: Also, you should for a UIView, initWithFrame: is the 'designated initializer', meaning this is the one that every other init lands on eventually. Scrub the vanilla init and move your setup code in to initWithFrame: instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are calling reload data too soon, probably in `initWithNibName`, you should be calling it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I will post the .m file After i got home. But i call the reloadData method After the Init. It gets called when new data comes in from a host.

Comment: Added m file under EDIT in question

Comment: Hello, I removed the init method and replaced the code in the initWithFrame to this:
   `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
     {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        
        [SharedSingeltons sharedInstance]._client.delegateCustomClient = self;
        _tableViewNextTitle.delegate = self;
        _tableViewNextTitle.dataSource = self;
    }
    return self;
} `

Still the tableView is null when I want to reload the datasource, as I said if have connected everything in the IB

Comment: Ok I made some investigation. When I init the view and the tableview get its data for the first time, the view instance looks like this:<NextTitleView: 0xb8a94b0; frame = (0 0; 300 430); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xb8a9520>>

But when I want to update the tableview the uiview instance looks like this: <NextTitleView: 0xa155820; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0xa155890>>

It seems the uiview instance is not the same :(..... The view is part of a UITableView which is pageable.

Answer (score 0):

I just set up a uiviewcontroller to handle the view. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that UIActionSheet led to the problem，you can try to reloadData twice.

Answer (score 0):

1. I noticed you are New-ing your Table view, but it's an Outlet...  You don't need to alloc init your table view, if it's an IBOutlet.   So either get rid of the IBOutlet, and just declare it as a property (but then you need to make sure you lay out your Table view programmatically), or keep the IBOutlet, and get rid of the code to alloc init it.  Currently also your datasource and delegate are set from IB, so if you alloc init your table view, those won't be set anymore...
2. The tableview outlet should NOT be nil.

Can you put a breakpoint in awakeFromNib, and see if the TableView outlet is NIL there?

Are you loading the View Class that contains the table view by using its NIB file properly?

If you just embed the View class in the storyboard, it will not load the NIB automatically.   I usually use a View container in that case, then load the NIB programmatically, and embed the loaded view in the view container programmatically.

```
NSArray *arrayXibObjects = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"net.mycompany.myappid"] loadNibNamed:@"myNibName" owner:nil options:nil];

for (id object in arrayXibObjects) {
   if ([object isKindOfClass:myNibsClass]) {
       return object;   // this is your class loaded from NIB
   }  
}
```

This code can be placed in a utility method, to make it accessible with 1 line of code.

The returned Class is going to have the IBOutlets connected from the NIB to it's respective Class.

Now check in the debugger:

```
po [loadedClassFromNib tableView] // should not be NIL
```

Then embed the loaded NIB in the container like this: (or use constraints)

```
[self.viewContainer addSubview: classLoadedFromNib];
classLoadedFromNib.frame = self.viewContainer.frame;
```